# why does it cause termination if I try to throw something inside a catch block in C++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw, gcc4

I have the following C++ code and it gives me a surprise.
The problem is that if I throw something except re-throw inside the catch block,
the program will be terminated by calling abort and give the error message in GCC4,
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'".
If I just use "throw;" to re-throw inside the catch block, everything will be fine.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try{
        throw std::string("first throw");
    }
    catch(std::string &x){
        try{
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
//          throw;  // if I use this line, all is fine.
            throw int(2); // but if I use this line, it causes Abort() to be called
        }
        catch (int &k){
            throw;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cout << "all handled here!"<< endl;
        }
    }
    catch(...){
        std::cout<< "never printed" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you throw from a catch this is to be expected.

Answer (score 13):

If you throw an `int`, then it won't be handled; it will be caught by the inner `catch (int &k)` handler, which rethrows it; and there is no outer handler to catch the rethrown exception, since you're already in an outer `catch` block. So in this case, `terminate` is called due to an unhandled exception.

If you rethrow the `string`, then it's caught by the inner `catch(...)` handler; this doesn't rethrow, so the exception has then been handled.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I think your answer is concise and right to the point.

Comment: Is it common/recommended practice to throw string ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: Usually, no; for reporting errors or other conditions that can't be handled locally, throw a custom type, usually a subclass of `std::exception`; and for other purposes you probably don't want to use exceptions in the first place. But for learning how exceptions work, `string` and `int` are as good as anything.

Answer (score 7):

You `throw` is not inside any `try` handler thus it leads to `abort` being called.

Here is your code with the indentation cleaned up a bit and some comments inline:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try {
        throw std::string("first throw");
    }
    catch (std::string &x) {
        try {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
            // throw;  // if I use this line, all is fine.
            throw int(2); // but if I use this line, it causes Abort() to be called
        }
        catch (int &k) {
            // Catches and rethrows exception. Not inside a try thus leads to abort.
            throw;
        }
        catch (...) {
            // Will handle the case where the string is rethrown instead. No abort.
            cout << "all handled here!"<< endl;
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout<< "never printed" << endl;
    }
}
```